# Is it possible to mark code so as to add custom entries to BBEdit's "Functions" menu?

Tags: mac, javascript, bbedit

I remember back in my CodeWarrior days, it was possible to add entries to the code navigational menu using `#pragma mark` directives, which made it easy to organize your code file into sections visible in the menu.

Is there any such way to do this in BBEdit, specifically in JavaScript files?

[image]

Comment: Voted to close and move to Stack Overflow - that's where the programmers hang out.

Comment: It's not really a *programming* question though, so I didn't want to post there. It's really just a question about the BBEdit application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BBEdit supports #pragma mark for non-C languages, actually.

See [the entry on the bbedit-hints blog](http://bbedit-hints.tumblr.com/post/11403705337/pragma-mark-in-bbedit-for-not-c-languages) on this topic.

Also: some other prefixes work (TODO, for example).

Comment: Brilliant! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Omg it even supports divider lines with "#mark -"! Amazing! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not an ideal solution, but I did find a way to add bookmarks to a file by parsing it with a regular expression. You can then start lines with a certain character sequence that you want to represent a mark.

[image]

(Here I'm using a triple-slash to identify a bookmark.)

The problem is you have to run this manually each time you want to build the menu--it doesn't update automatically.

It also doesn't support "-" divider lines like CodeWarrior used to. Bummer.